# Do you have a better way to cater to the need to express something as being "uncatered" to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasing

I needed "cater" as an adjective today, and I didn't enjoy how it worked out; and not only due to the spell checked thumbing its nose at me.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncatered appears to indicate the word is kosher, but in the following paragraph it felt like a speed bump.

> I've come to be mildly annoyed by all of them over time: they're each good for something, none is good at everything, and I still have plenty of uncatered to problems.

Comment: Some caterers are kosher; some aren't.

Comment: HA! I see what you did there, @deadrat

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to address the need to express that.

> I've come to be mildly annoyed by all of them over time: they're each good for something, none is good at everything, and I still have plenty of *unaddressed* problems.

Some definitions of *address*:

Oxford: "Think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem): *a fundamental problem has still to be addressed*."

Merriam-Webster: "Direct the efforts or attention of (oneself): *will address himself to the problem*" or "to deal with or treat: *intrigued by the chance to address important issues — I. L. Horowitz*".

Cambridge: "Give attention to or deal with a matter or problem: *The issue of funding has yet to be addressed.*"

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions about taking care of problems (or rather, not taking care of them) captures the sense of "catered" that means special, solicitous care.

I suggest that the speed bump you hit with "catered to problems" is the same one that will throw your readers -- the unfortunate attraction of the preposition "**to**" to the noun "**problems**," as in

> I address my attention **to problems**.

With "catered to," that's not a possible parse, but it's enough to feel the bump.

I further suggest that the solution is adopt Little Eva's phrasing to place your modifier after the noun:

> I still have plenty of problems [left] uncatered to.

Answer (score 0):

Catering **to** the problems is slightly different to catering **for** the problems but, presuming you mean the problems are not fixed and not just not attempted, I suggest this:

> and I still have plenty of unresolved problems.

Answer (score 0):

Op could use the *verb* **attend** or the *adjective*, **unattended**, e.g.:

**1**. “I still have plenty of problems not *attended* to.”

**2**. “I still have plenty of problems left *unattended*.”

---

> [**attend**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=attend+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=attend+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.10.1432301...........0.0F0RDp6_a6I&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: **2**. deal with. "he muttered that he had business to *attend* to"
>
> *synonyms*: deal with, see to, manage, organize, sort out, handle, take care of, take charge of, take in hand, tackle. (Google)

---

> [**unattended**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=unattended+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=unattended+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.8768...........0.4SUKfNXnMfQ&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: not noticed or dealt with. "her behavior went unnoticed and *unattended* to"
>
> *synonyms*: ignored, disregarded, neglected. (Google)

Answer (score 0):

"... I still have plenty of ***unmet*** *needs*."

"Unmet" -- not fulfilled-- seems to be used primarily in this context.  It is better than "unfulfilled" for your purposes because it implies a more specific actor other than yourself. It's perhaps a perfect synonym for *unaddressed*, but it's less of a mouthful.